# Filtering output to needed values in json

Tags: json, filter

I have below output generated as part of gathering all attributes about openstack VM. I am trying to work a json filter, which would let me select just values of interest. (tenant name, tenant ID or cloud name and so on). 
I am new to filters, so all the help is appreciated. I tried different ways but not close to what i want.

```
N_ID": true, 
  "NAME_ATTR": "name", 
  "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "AUTO", 
  "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "cloud-b", 
  "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1, 
  "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null, 
  "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active", 
  "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2018-06-05T22:45:50.000000", 
  "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null, 
  "accessIPv4": "192.168.0.1", 
  "accessIPv6": "", 
  "addresses": {
    "tenant-internal-direct-net": [
      {
        "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:73:c6:9e", 
        "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed", 
        "addr": "192.168.0.1", 
        "version": 4
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "az": "cloud-1-b", 
  "cloud": "cloud-1", 
  "config_drive": "", 
  "created": "2018-06-05T22:45:37Z", 
  "flavor": {
    "id": "15", 
    "name": "2vCPUx8GB"
  }, 
  "hostId": "f12acb7a6a4050672a7710da4ccb5987916ac46648fc667496c4a169", 
  "human_id": "myhost-ost1", 
  "id": "ae12d6cd-c9b8-4908-a0f9-6af614f01197", 
  "image": {
    "id": ""
  }, 
  "interface_ip": "192.168.0.1", 
  "key_name": "pz-rhel7", 
  "metadata": {}, 
  "name": "myhost-ost1", 
  "networks": {
    "tenant-internal-direct-net": [
      "192.168.0.1"
    ]
  }, 
  "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [
    {
      "id": "179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1"
    }
  ], 
  "private_v4": "", 
  "progress": 0, 
  "public_v4": "192.168.0.1", 
  "public_v6": "", 
  "region": "cloud-1", 
  "request_ids": [], 
  "security_groups": [
    {
      "description": "", 
      "id": "55991c66-beb5-4750-b8f6-06025a1ce7d4", 
      "name": "SSHping", 
      "security_group_rules": [
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "53fa8fca-d54c-4462-9f5e-a748fed86885", 
          "port_range_max": null, 
          "port_range_min": null, 
          "protocol": "icmp", 
          "remote_ip_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0", 
          "security_group_id": "55991c66-beb5-4750-b8f6-06025a1ce7d4"
        }, 
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "841446f5-a7bf-46e9-91c2-f505c5842bc6", 
          "port_range_max": 22, 
          "port_range_min": 22, 
          "protocol": "tcp", 
          "remote_ip_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0", 
          "security_group_id": "55991c66-beb5-4750-b8f6-06025a1ce7d4"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Default security group", 
      "id": "987efb61-d7f3-47d5-9362-42f66d1b104b", 
      "name": "default", 
      "security_group_rules": [
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "79da1cc2-2128-4937-95ca-d0fc757bbfb3", 
          "port_range_max": 22, 
          "port_range_min": 22, 
          "protocol": "tcp", 
          "remote_ip_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0", 
          "security_group_id": "987efb61-d7f3-47d5-9362-42f66d1b104b"
        }, 
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "901d230e-9cd5-486c-aa89-c279b359fac9", 
          "port_range_max": 1, 
          "port_range_min": 1, 
          "protocol": "tcp", 
          "remote_ip_prefix": "0.0.0.0/0", 
          "security_group_id": "987efb61-d7f3-47d5-9362-42f66d1b104b"
        }, 
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "950c6b8c-e129-4138-8dd5-92254c5bd6c8", 
          "port_range_max": null, 
          "port_range_min": null, 
          "protocol": null, 
          "remote_ip_prefix": null, 
          "security_group_id": "987efb61-d7f3-47d5-9362-42f66d1b104b"
        }, 
        {
          "direction": "ingress", 
          "ethertype": "IPv4", 
          "id": "cf20d16d-0b8a-4bd7-b6b4-cab6d5968a44", 
          "port_range_max": null, 
          "port_range_min": null, 
          "protocol": null, 
          "remote_ip_prefix": null, 
          "security_group_id": "987efb61-d7f3-47d5-9362-42f66d1b104b"
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "status": "ACTIVE", 
  "tenant_id": "99f1f837a8004092926887d46188e726", 
  "updated": "2018-06-05T22:45:50Z", 
  "user_id": "35f6e9300037f9c6d23f08c5af8b324c4ab23688d2a146bd6aac601377ed72ef", 
  "volumes": [
    {
      "HUMAN_ID": false, 
      "NAME_ATTR": "name", 
      "attachments": [
        {
          "attached_at": "2018-06-05T22:45:43.000000", 
          "attachment_id": "4602ad6b-8652-4702-910b-e4e82a894a32", 
          "device": "/dev/vda", 
          "host_name": null, 
          "id": "179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1", 
          "server_id": "ae12d6cd-c9b8-4908-a0f9-6af614f01197", 
          "volume_id": "179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1"
        }
      ], 
      "availability_zone": "nova", 
      "bootable": true, 
      "consistencygroup_id": null, 
      "created_at": "2018-06-05T22:45:39.000000", 
      "description": "", 
      "device": "/dev/vda", 
      "display_description": "", 
      "display_name": "", 
      "encrypted": false, 
      "human_id": null, 
      "id": "179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1", 
      "links": [
        {
          "href": "http://cloud-1.mycloud.com:8776/v2/99f1f837a8004092926887d46188e726/volumes/179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1", 
          "rel": "self"
        }, 
        {
          "href": "http://cloud-1.mycloud.com:8776/99f1f837a8004092926887d46188e726/volumes/179749a7-ba9b-4cc1-aebd-dcc8dcb7f4e1", 
          "rel": "bookmark"
        }
      ], 
      "metadata": {
        "attached_mode": "rw", 
        "readonly": "False"
      }, 
      "multiattach": false, 
      "name": "", 
      "os-vol-tenant-attr:tenant_id": "99f1f837a8004092926887d46188e726", 
      "replication_status": "disabled", 
      "request_ids": [], 
      "size": 11, 
      "snapshot_id": null, 
      "source_volid": null, 
      "status": "in-use", 
      "updated_at": "2018-06-05T22:45:43.000000", 
      "user_id": "35f6e9300037f9c6d23f08c5af8b324c4ab23688d2a146bd6aac601377ed72ef", 
      "volume_image_metadata": {
        "checksum": "2d3f40fa841b1c35c10e74207d1221f8", 
        "container_format": "bare", 
        "disk_format": "raw", 
        "hw_disk_bus": "scsi", 
        "hw_qemu_guest_agent": "yes", 
        "hw_scsi_model": "virtio-scsi", 
        "hw_vif_multiqueue_enabled": "true", 
        "hw_watchdog_action": "reset", 
        "image_id": "fe463cc5-fecf-4aad-a77e-70987f421169", 
        "image_name": "RHEL-7_4-MG", 
        "min_disk": "0", 
        "min_ram": "0", 
        "size": "10737418240"
      }, 
      "volume_type": "ceph-standard", 
      "x_openstack_request_ids": []
    }
  ], 
  "x_openstack_request_ids": []
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1. Please fix the sample JSON. 2. Please follow the mcve guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (especially the "minimal" part!).  3. You have tagged this Q with just `json filter` but many JSON experts may not know which keys correspond to "tenant name", etc; please explicitly identify the keys you have in mind.

Comment: hi sorry for confusion. I think i got a error while submitting about fixing the code, so i did that. Need to do anything more ?

Comment: Also, mostly i need to derive something out of the output what's pasted above. So mainly filtering the values of interest from output.